# How to get APP ID and parse Server without account in parse

Tags: parse-platform

Parse not allowing us to create an account now how to get the app id and parse server now.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
    .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
    .server("http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse")

    ...

    .build()
);
```

Comment: just make it up... parse.com and parse-server are not connected directly

Comment: how to get them now.

Comment: Any string will do